# Convergent $\sum^{\infty}_{n = 1} a_n \nRightarrow \sum^{\infty}_{n = 1} a^k_n$ converges absolutely for some k

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Consider convergent series $\sum^{\infty}_{n = 1} a_n$.
>
> Prove that the following is false: there exists integer $k > 0$ such that
>   $\sum^{\infty}_{n = 1} a^k_n$ converges absolutely.

Please give me a hint how to proceed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not quite sure that I understand the question, but it sounds like you have to find a convergent series $\sum a_n$ such that for any $k \in \mathbb{N}$, the series $\sum_n a_n^k$ does not converge absolutely...

If this is the case, try setting $a_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{\log n}$.

Comment: Thank you, for unknown reason, I used to think that $\frac{1}{\log n}$ follows the same pattern as $\frac{1}{n}$, i.e. it's converges when taking into power of 2 and higher.

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely get your question. But I have some results they may helps you.

> Let $\sum a_n$ be a convergent sequence of non-negative terms. Then $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$ and therefore $0\le a_n\lt 1$ for sufficiently large $n.$
>   Let $k\gt 1$ then $$0\le a_n^k\le a_n\implies\sum a_n^k \,\,\,\,\,\,\text{is converges absolutely}$$

If you are looking for a counter example, I think alternating $p$ series will helps you.
Consider $b_n=\dfrac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $k=2$ then $$\sum b_n^{k} \,\,\,\,\,\,\text{is divergent}.$$

Comment: k needs to be an integer, but thank you anyway. Have a look at Shalop's answer.

Comment: Dear Nilan. Sorry for my misleading wording, but the counterexample I was looking for should be such that *for any* integer k the series fails to converge absolutely.